# Solve pde using laplace?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have to solve the following pde using Laplace transforms:

$xw_x + w_t= xt$ i.c: w(x,0)= 0

Firstly, transforming the above wrt t, i get:
$\bar{w_x} + s\bar{w}/x = 1/s^2$

But, in the textbook, the transformation is given as :
$\bar{w_x} + s/x = 1/s^2$
Why is there no $\bar{w}$ on the LHS in the textbook answer?

definition of Laplace transform from textbook:
$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}u(t)dt$

Lalpace transform used:
$L(u')= s\bar{u} - u_0$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It would be helpful if you would include your definition of Laplace transform. Could you do that?

Comment: That is not a good definition of the Laplace transform, it should be regarded as a theorem which follows from the actual definition. That definition should be $L(u)(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st} u(t) dt$. Without that, where would the $1/s^2$ come from?

Answer (score 0):

Solve ODE
$$\bar{w}_x + s\bar{w}/x = 1/s^2,\;\bar{w}(0)=0$$ 
$$\bar{w}=\frac{x}{{{s}^{3}}+{{s}^{2}}}=\frac{x}{s+1}-\frac{x}{s}+\frac{x}{{{s}^{2}}}$$
Answer:
$$w={{e}^{-t}} x+t x-x$$